# AMADEUS order api is returning detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.DecompressionFailureAtRequest"}}

Tags: spring-boot, amadeus

I am calling amadeus order API inside spring boot application using feign but i am getting Decompression issues

Request :

```json
{
    "data": {
        "type": "flight-order",
        "flightOffers": [
            {
                "type": "flight-offer",
                "id": "1",
                "source": "GDS",
                "instantTicketingRequired": false,
                "disablePricing": false,
                "nonHomogeneous": false,
                "oneWay": false,
                "paymentCardRequired": false,
                "lastTicketingDate": "2024-03-21",
                "lastTicketingDateTime": "2024-03-21",
                "numberOfBookableSeats": 9,
                "itineraries": [
                    {
                        "duration": "PT6H50M",
                        "segments": [
                            {
                                "id": "99",
                                "numberOfStops": 0,
                                "blacklistedInEU": false,
                                "co2Emissions": null,
                                "departure": {
                                    "iataCode": "JFK",
                                    "terminal": "4",
                                    "at": "2024-10-01T08:05:00"
                                },
                                "arrival": {
                                    "iataCode": "LHR",
                                    "terminal": "3",
                                    "at": "2024-10-01T19:55:00"
                                },
                                "carrierCode": "VS",
                                "number": "26",
                                "aircraft": {
                                    "code": "351"
                                },
                                "operating": {
                                    "carrierCode": "VS"
                                },
                                "duration": "PT6H50M",
                                "stops": null
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "price": {
                    "margin": null,
                    "grandTotal": "387.30",
                    "billingCurrency": "USD",
                    "additionalServices": null,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "total": "387.30",
                    "base": "150.00",
                    "fees": [
                        {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "type": "SUPPLIER"
                        },
                        {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "type": "TICKETING"
                        }
                    ],
                    "taxes": null,
                    "refundableTaxes": "387.30"
                },
                "pricingOptions": {
                    "includedCheckedBagsOnly": false,
                    "refundableFare": false,
                    "noRestrictionFare": false,
                    "noPenaltyFare": false,
                    "fareType": [
                        "PUBLISHED"
                    ]
                },
                "validatingAirlineCodes": [
                    "VS"
                ],
                "travelerPricings": [
                    {
                        "travelerId": "1",
                        "fareOption": "STANDARD",
                        "travelerType": "ADULT",
                        "associatedAdultId": null,
                        "price": {
                            "margin": null,
                            "grandTotal": null,
                            "billingCurrency": "USD",
                            "additionalServices": null,
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "total": "387.30",
                            "base": "150.00",
                            "fees": null,
                            "taxes": null,
                            "refundableTaxes": "387.30"
                        },
                        "fareDetailsBySegment": [
                            {
                                "segmentId": "99",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "XLX89NB7",
                                "brandedFare": "LIGHT",
                                "allotmentDetails": null,
                                "sliceDiceIndicator": null,
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 0,
                                    "weight": 0,
                                    "weightUnit": null
                                },
                                "additionalServices": null,
                                "allotment": false,
                                "class": "T"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "travelers": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "dateOfBirth": "1982-01-16",
                "gender": "MALE",
                "name": {
                    "firstName": "Boniface",
                    "lastName": "Kaghusa",
                    "middleName": "Mutanava",
                    "secondLastName": "Bojos"
                },
                "contact": {
                    "purpose": "STANDARD",
                    "phones": [
                        {
                            "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                            "countryCallingCode": "250",
                            "number": "785481627"
                        }
                    ],
                    "companyName": "THRYPES",
                    "emailAddress": "bojosmuta@gmail.com"
                },
                "documents": [
                    {
                        "number": "00000000",
                        "issuanceDate": "2015-04-14",
                        "expiryDate": "2025-04-14",
                        "issuanceCountry": "ES",
                        "issuanceLocation": "Madrid",
                        "nationality": "ES",
                        "birthPlace": "Madrid",
                        "documentType": "PASSPORT",
                        "validityCountry": "ES",
                        "birthCountry": null,
                        "holder": true
                    }
                ],
                "emergencyContact": null,
                "loyaltyPrograms": null,
                "discountEligibility": null
            }
        ],
        "remarks": {
            "general": [
                {
                    "subType": "GENERAL_MISCELLANEOUS",
                    "category": null,
                    "text": "OK",
                    "travelerIds": null,
                    "flightOfferIds": null
                }
            ]
        },
        "ticketingAgreement": null,
        "automatedProcess": null,
        "contacts": [
            {
                "purpose": "STANDARD",
                "phones": [
                    {
                        "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                        "countryCallingCode": "250",
                        "number": "785481627"
                    }
                ],
                "companyName": "ok",
                "emailAddress": "bojos@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "formOfIdentifications": null
    }
}
```

response getting

```json
{
    "fault":{
        "faultstring":"Decompression failure at request",
        "detail":{
            "errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.DecompressionFailureAtRequest"
        }
    }
}
```

below is Feign definition

```java
@PostMapping("/v1/booking/flight-orders")
Response flightOffersOrder(@RequestBody AmadeusOrderData amadeusOrderData , @RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorizationHeader);
```

I want to know what can be the issue in my request